# Post adding grpc-server-spring-boot-starter dependency application is not starting

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

After I added the following grpc-server-spring-boot-starter dependency, my application threw the following error while starting the server.

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'shadedNettyGrpcServerLifecycle'; nested exception is
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
> io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerImplBuilder.delegate()Lio/grpc/ServerBuilder;
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
> ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
> ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
> ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
> [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
> [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
> [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
> [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

I just added the following dependency to my spring-boot project before it started throwing errors.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Add some additional info, please.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I followed the steps mentioned below:

1. Delete the .idea folder & invalidate the cache.
2. Removed maven-compiler-plugin from plugins
3. Added the following dependency in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
       <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
       <version>2.12.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```